# Sharing validation between two models with fluent validaition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I have two different models. In both models some of the validations are the same and some aren't. Is there any way to share parts of validation with fluent validation? So I don't have to maintain duplicate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`SetValidator`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom) method:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SomeComplexProperty).SetValidator(new MyValidator());
```